# cannot start up pepProxy service on FIWARE orion context broker instance

Tags: fiware-orion

I have created an orion context broker instance (FIWARE cloud portal image) that seems like with pepProxy installed. When I run "service pepProxy start" here is the feedback from the terminal:
Starting...
pepProxy dead but pid file exists
Starting pepProxy...                              Success

When check the status with "service pepProxy status", it says:
pepProxy dead but pid file exists

What can be done?

Answer (score 0):

It seems something is preventing the PEP Proxy from starting. Have you checked "/var/log/pepProxy"? Please, also check what port the PEP Proxy is trying to bind to (usually 1026) and whether there is any other process actually running on that port (maybe the Context Broker is already running in that standard port).

In case the problem is a port conflict, you should change the Context Broker port in /etc/sysconfig/contextBroker or the one of the PEP Proxy in /etc/sysconfig/pepProxy.

If that's not the problem we would need some more information in order to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes it is started up if I change the port in context broker.